# JPA OneToMany-Mapping without mapping class for Many-side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In a Spring Boot application using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate, there are two (PostgreSQL) tables of interest:

```
entity                                external_id
--                                    --
id serial                             id serial
...                                   entity_id int
...                                   external_id int
```

The relation between entity and external_ids is obviously OneToMany, which I want to use in the JPA mapping as well. A simple way to do this is to create @Entity-mappings for each table and use a @OneToMany-relation:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy= "entityId")
  private Set<ExternalId> externalIds;
}

@Entity
public class ExternalId {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Integer entityId;

  private Integer externalId;
}
```

But since the table external_ids just holds a list of numbers for each member of entity, I would like to go without an explicit mapping of the table external_id and immediately map the values of external_id.external_id:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(???)
  private Set<Integer> externalIds;
}
```

Is this possible with JPA 2.1 and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize [`@ElementCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) for this purpose:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "TableName", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "JoinColumnName"))
private Set<Integer> externalIds;
```

Comment: This would only work with a class mapping the target - as ExternalId does in the first code snippet. It does not work for mapping a column of the target table to a Set of the source mapping class.

Comment: I mean mapping the column external_id.external_id onto a Set (or List if that makes a difference) of the class Entity, which is a mapping onto a *different table (Entity)*. Yes, I read your whole answer and yes I tried it. Hibernate then expects the class Integer you use to be a mapping onto the table external_id, which it is not, so it throws an AnnotationException "Use of @OneToMany [...] targeting an unmapped class". In essence, your suggestion is a different way of writing my first code snippet, not a solution for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @sheltem I am sorry, my fault. Please, see my edited answer.

Comment: Just found a similar explanation in the JavaPersistence wikibook. The given example is exactly what I want and works once applied to my domain: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Basic_Collections Which also makes your new answer correct. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Useful answer, note that to point the external id column, we could add a `@Column(name="id_external")` to what's posted above (like the given link suggests).